# grep number filename[10-25]

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I have several log files:

```
log.2021-01-01_01.gz
log.2021-01-01_02.gz
log.2021-01-02_01.gz
log.2021-01-02_02.gz
log.2021-01-16_01.gz
```

And I would like to search for a pattern (number) in multiple files (ranging from the 10 of january to the 26th of january).

I tried something like this:

```
zgrep 13456 log.2021-01-[10-26]*.gz
```

This to match all the dates in the range and including all the parts after `"_01" "_02"`.

But this doesn't seem to work,
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Use `{10..26}` instead of `[10-26]`. Note that it will generate filenames that might not match existing files in which case `grep` would raise an error

Comment: You can avoid seeing the error from non-existent files by adding the `-s` option to `grep`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your quick reply

Comment: [10-26] is not a valid glob for 10,11,12...26 but 0,1,2,6